# Use Facebook's iOS SDK to check in with a photo

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently able to post photos and check into places fine using the me/photos and me/checkins graph API. But is there a way to combine the two and post a photo to a user's album with a location tagged to it?

Thanks in advance. 
Ricky.

Answer (score 0):

What about the 'place' field in the photo table? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
You can set an object containing long, lat, country, and other fields. Not sure how that will look when viewed through facebook on the website though.

Comment: When I try to make this post I receive an error saying that I need to pass up an "ID" string, which makes me think this is a GET parameter. Plus, doing an FBRequest of nearby places doesn't return me page references, just the place IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a facebook page in the 'place' field when uploading a photo to Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos